# ViewStart.cshtml is not getting rendered in Custom View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have defined my custome view engine as below just to add more locations to search for.

```
public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        private static string[] AdditionalViewLocations = new[]
        {
            "~/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
        };

        public CustomViewEngine() : base()
        {
            MasterLocationFormats = MasterLocationFormats.Union(AdditionalViewLocations).ToArray();
            PartialViewLocationFormats = PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(AdditionalViewLocations).ToArray();
            ViewLocationFormats = ViewLocationFormats.Union(AdditionalViewLocations).ToArray();

        }
    }
```

Now issue i am facing is, the layout is not getting applied for any of the views which was set in _ViewStart.cshtml page. Appreciates your help.

Comment: Can you explain how *layout is not getting applied for any of the views*? Is that all view pages styling are broken (and throwing client-side errors) after adding custom view engine?

Comment: Yes,all stylings are broken and no content from _Layout.cshtml is coming. I have this in my _ViewStart.cshtml. @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto just to add one thing. there are no client side errors

Comment: the engine looks for the viewstart in the folder hierarchy of the view. So since you use other locations than the Views folder, you sould put the viewstart at the root of the application

Comment: @J.Loscos: Thanks.After keeping into root directory,this has worked.

Comment: @J.Loscos, Why can't you add it as an answer if that helped @Parashuram? Answers will be having more focus and that will really help someone with the same issue.